# Ionic Time and Date Picker

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I added a time picker in my app but it returns the time in the format HH:MM. 
I want the time picker to return the format HH:MM:SS so that the input is compatible with mySQL time format as well.

```
 <ion-input type="time" [(ngModel)]="ChildData.Temperaturedatetime"></ion-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Component docs:](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/#iso-8601-datetime-format-yyyy-mm-ddthh-mmz)

> The datetime picker provides the simplicity of selecting an exact
>   format, and persists the datetime values as a string using the
>   standardized ISO 8601 datetime format. However, it's important to note
>   that ion-datetime does not attempt to solve all situtations when
>   validating and manipulating datetime values. If datetime values need
>   to be parsed from a certain format, or manipulated (such as adding 5
>   days to a date, subtracting 30 minutes, etc.), or even formatting data
>   to a specific locale, then we highly recommend using moment.js to
>   "Parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates in JavaScript".
>   Moment.js has quickly become our goto standard when dealing with
>   datetimes within JavaScript, but Ionic does not prepackage this
>   dependency since most apps will not require it, and its locale
>   configuration should be decided by the end-developer.